# Non of the Firestore task handlers are being called if there is no matching document for query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a simple code that checks if a document exists containing a specified email address. But if the email does not exist and no matching documents neither `addOnCompleteListener` or `addOnSuccessListner` or `addOnFailureListener` are not getting called.

```
val db = Firebase.firestore

db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email", "nonexisting@example.com").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {  QuerySnapshot ->
            Log.d(TAG, "${QuerySnapshot.documents.size}")
        }
        .addOnCanceledListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "Request was canceled!")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "$exception")
        }
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                for (document in task.result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id}")
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
            }
        }
```

As I understand this is not the expected behavior. Am I missing something here?

I am using the following as dependencies:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
```

**Update**:

I tried `bom:29.1.0` still the same behavior, I do have internet, mutations like `add()` works fine

Comment: Just to be sure: if you place a `Log.d(TAG, "Starting query")` just before the query, that *does* show up,  but none of the other logs do?

Comment: I think your task is completed succesfully but you dont have any match for this email that the reason its show nothing use just a simple success log before for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your query yields no results, `addOnFailureListener` won't be triggered, since the absence of some documents won't be considered an Exception. However, if your query will be rejected due to improper security rules, then an Exception will be thrown for sure.

You say that `addOnCompleteListener` is also not triggered when your query doesn't return any documents. But I doubt it since you say that `add()` works fine, meaning that you have an internet connection on the user device. Most likely it's triggered but you don't know it. Why? Because you aren't handling that case.

If you get no results, `addOnCompleteListener` indeed fires, meaning that `task.isSuccessful` returns true. This also means that the else part won't be evaluated. Since there are no documents, the for-each loop won't print anything. The best option that you have is to check the documents for existence:

```
.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in task.result) {
            if(document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "${document.id}")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Document doesn't exist.")
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried stepping with debugger it does not step inside the `addOnCompleteListener` at all.

Comment: Then most likely you don't have an internet connection on the user device or the code in your class isn't triggered. If you add the log statement, as Frank suggested in his comment, are you getting any output?

Comment: Thanks for the support so far. I tested the code now, added Franks suggested log statement, strangely now it works now. Before I really saw debugger jumping from one task handler to another and exit the function. I think this is probably a caching issue in android studio, because I changed the app icon which may have result in app rebuild before I retrying with Frank's suggested log statement.

Comment: When you have trouble with the UI, then `Invalidate Caches` might solve the issue. However, your code didn't handle the situation to check if the document doesn't exist. Did my answer help you?

Comment: Was helpful, so I gave an upvote to your answer. I was missing `document.exists()` if check.

Comment: You are correct my mistake null check was the issue. so I accepted the answer.  and  today also I came across this jumps because I was using auto fixes for `!!` which suggest `?: return@addOnCompleteListener`, what I should have really done is surround with null check or use `let`. Thanks again for help! probably my ADHD nature was not paying good enough attention to your answer.